What are some mantras which can give me fearlessness and strong heart?
What mantras or stotras can give the upasaka immense courage , mental strength , lion like will and fearlessness?

One reference you might like.

Ādityahṛdayam (आदित्यहृदयम्) is a Hindu devotional hymn, dedicated to Āditya(आदित्य/Sūrya/the Sun God), found in the Yuddha Kānda (6.105) of Vālmīki's Rāmāyana. It was recited by the Maharishi Agastya to Sri Rāma in the battlefield before fighting with the Rākshasa king Rāvaṇa. In it, Agastya teaches Sri Rāma the procedure of worshiping Āditya for mental strength and courage in order to defeat the enemy.
Refer the following link for Āditya Hridayam Stotram in Sanskrit and English with Meaning.
Good Luck!
